# Trouble fetching a link from a dynamic webpage

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping

I've written a script in python in combination with selenium to parse a certain link from a webpage. The link is within an `iframe`. I've tried to switch to it but can't read the content from it to fetch that specific link I'm after.

Here is how to get there:

1. There is a link to log-in which is free.
2. After logging in, the website automatically leads to the first page of the desired content.
3. There are few names (members) there, which have links connected to each of their profile.
4. After going in that profile page there is a link to their present company (located under professional experience) which is what I wish to parse.

The desired link (under proffessional experience) within the first profile looks [like this](https://www.dropbox.com/s/q4zvpt09pus04na/Untitled.jpg?dl=0):

[This is the log in link](https://login.xing.com/continue?dest_url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.xing.com%2Fcommunities%2Fgroups%2Ffuhrpark-update-68fe-1076244%2Fmember_states%3Fsorting%3Dalphabetical&force_dest=1)

This is the script I've tried so far with:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from urllib.parse import urljoin
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

link = "https://www.xing.com"

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get("replace with above link")
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)

wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "#login_form_username"))).send_keys("user")
wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "#login_form_password"))).send_keys("pass",Keys.RETURN)

links = [urljoin(link,items.find_element_by_css_selector(".user-name").get_attribute("href")) for items in wait.until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, ".contact")))]
for link in links:
    driver.get(link)
    name = wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "h2 span"))).text
    wait.until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it(driver.find_element_by_css_selector("#tab-content")))
    #I get timeout exception in the following line
    link = wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, ".job-company-name a"))).text
    print(name,link)
```

I don't know if this is helpful. Anyaways, [link to the source](https://www.dropbox.com/s/pl69yxtl6dzohp0/source%20code.txt?dl=0)

Comment: What is the current output? You can successfully switch to frame, but getting `NoSuchElementException` on `ilink` definition?

Comment: In your answer you're using search by `@id` to find iframe, while in your question - search by tag name... In case there are more than one `iframe` on page you might switch to wrong `iframe` which doesn't contain required element

Comment: Sir, i tried with both of them.

Comment: It's hard to tell what's wrong without seeing the page source. IMHO your solution is not the best way to deal with iframes... :)

Comment: This is not actually a solution, just a workaround.

Comment: You said you got `TimeoutException`. You mean you used explicit wait to find link inside an iframe? It's not reflected in your question

Comment: This is originally how i tried. As I keep trying in different ways so in question I showed one of such. See the edit sir.

Comment: Check out the edit sir. I've included source code.

Comment: I'm afraid I see no elements with class name `job-company-name`

Comment: If this portion help you solve this sir. Please take a look at [this image](https://www.dropbox.com/s/pmm84836hdw3wj2/Untitled1.jpg?dl=0). I tried to wrap the information to fit the important portion within the image.

Comment: The same problem - I see no elements on page with class name `job-company-name` and no links, so it's hard to tell what's wrong with the code

Answer (score 0):

It seems I've found out a solution to deal with the problem. I'm ready to take out my answer If any better solution comes along:

```
links = [urljoin(link,items.find_element_by_css_selector(".user-name").get_attribute("href")) for items in wait.until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, ".contact")))]
for link in links:
    driver.get(link)
    name = wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "h2 span"))).text
    ilink = driver.find_element_by_css_selector("#tab-content").get_attribute("src")
    driver.get(ilink)   #this is what I did to get around that
    try:
        link = driver.find_element_by_css_selector(".job-company-name a").text
    except Exception: link = ""
    print(name,link)
```

Instead of switching to iframe I just parsed the link within iframe and made use of it. This is not the solution I expected but it works.